# Failed to post notification on channel if application is active

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am trying to integrate firebase notifications and I get a "failed to post notification on channel" error when trying to process received notifications.

This issue only happens when application is in the foregroud.

If it is in the background, notifications are displayed without a problem.

I am trying to post to a channel id "12345". I am not sure if this might be the issue, since I am not creating the channel, but if that is the problem, how is it working if the app is in the background?

What am I missing?

I am not using Android 8, and I actually found a snippet that should be used in that case to create a channel:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        }


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    // 0 is request code
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // 0 is id of notification
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Post your code that generates the notification.

Comment: I realize you are not currently using the snippet you posted to create a channel.  If you do ever use it, a correction is needed.  At the end, add a call to [NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).

Comment: @BobSnyder I just added the remainder of the code. the if part is not executed with version below 8, and that is what is executing in my emulator. What am I missing?

Comment: You indicate you are running on an emulator with API level < 26.  What is the API level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My logic above had an error that I missed. The problem was in versions >= 26, because I was creating a channel and then instead of sending the notification to the correct notification manager, I was creating a new instance of the notification manager (view last 2 lines of the question code).

Here is the corrected logic:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // create channel in new versions of android
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }


    // show notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    // 0 is request code
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_contact_purple)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // 0 is id of notification
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Thank you. There are hundreds of similar code that didn't work including the official guide but this finally worked for me. No idea why is down voted.

Comment: @AdamMendoza beats me too... but unfortunately seems there are people in stackoverflow whose only task is to view questions and answers and downvote them. would still like to see a feature in this where I could see who downvoted, and request at least clarification as to why they did.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the notification channel:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});  
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

If the **Firebase Notification** does not contain a data payload, Firebase automatically handles the notification when your application is in background.
That's why it is working in background.
See this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: What about for versions below 26? this is exactly why I have the if above. The NotificationChannel creation method requires version 26.

Comment: This answer correctly explains the background behavior.